Spatie Browsershot ERROR: The process “any number” was not found
I have been struggling with the following error all day today
I then took a look at the process. A few Chrome processes are created, terminated again after some time, but unfortunately no PDFs are created
The error message is:
The command ""C:/Users/cliann/Pictures/nodejs/node.exe" "C:\Projekte\Laravel\auDb\vendor\spatie\browsershot\src/../bin/browser.cjs" "{""url"":""file:\/\/C:\\Users\\cliann\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\794670098-0394288001717621531\\index.html"",""action"":""pdf"",""options"":{""path"":""test.pdf"",""args"":[],""viewport"":{""width"":800,""height"":600},""displayHeaderFooter"":false,""executablePath"":""C:\/Users\/cliann\/AppData\/Local\/Google\/Chrome\/Application\/chrome.exe""}}"" failed. Exit Code: 1(General error) Working directory: C:\Projekte\Laravel\auDb\public Output: ================ Error Output: ================ TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded at new Deferred (C:\Projekte\Laravel\auDb\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\util\Deferred.js:59:34) at Deferred.create (C:\Projekte\Laravel\auDb\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\util\Deferred.js:21:16) at new LifecycleWatcher (C:\Projekte\Laravel\auDb\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\cdp\LifecycleWatcher.js:66:60) at CdpFrame.goto (C:\Projekte\Laravel\auDb\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\cdp\Frame.js:140:29) at CdpFrame.<anonymous> (C:\Projekte\Laravel\auDb\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\util\decorators.js:98:27) at CdpPage.goto (C:\Projekte\Laravel\auDb\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\api\Page.js:585:43) at callChrome (C:\Projekte\Laravel\auDb\vendor\spatie\browsershot\bin\browser.cjs:277:37) ERROR: The process “ANY NUMBER” was not found..

My code looks like this:
$html = view('pdfs.offer', [
            'invoiceNumber' => '123',
            'customerName' => 'test',
        ])->render();


        //this works
        Browsershot::url('https://example.com')
            ->setNodeBinary(config('app.node_binary'))
            ->setNpmBinary(config('app.npm_binary'))
            ->setChromePath(config('app.chrome_path'))
            ->savePdf('example.pdf');

        //this does not work
        Browsershot::html($html)
            ->setNodeBinary(config('app.node_binary'))
            ->setNpmBinary(config('app.npm_binary'))
            ->setChromePath(config('app.chrome_path'))
            ->savePdf('test.pdf');

Can anyone tell me what the problem is? Here is the Laravel output : HERE
I am really desperate ...
Windows 10
Laravel Version: 10.42
NodeJs Version: 22.02
Browsershot version: 4.0
Putteteer Version: 22.10
I have already reinstalled the packages, adjusted the paths, asked AI and searched several forums.

I have just found out that the following causes the problem
´´´



´´´
Does anyone know how else to add pictures?